# QTableView and unique IDs

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

I'm new to Qt and coming from C# .Net. I am trying to replicate a fairly simple program I wrote in C# in Qt as a learning tool. I have a data model that inherits QAbstractTableModel and implements:

rowCount,
columnCount,
data,
setData,
headerData
flags

My data structure is a map

```
std::map<int, CBDataRow>
```

So the idea was that each row would have a unique int ID and a struct containing the rest of the row information.

What I am stuck on now is how to update my data model when the user makes an edit in the QTableView object. The setData function does get called. Here it is:

```
bool CBDatabaseModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role) {
    bool success = false;
    if(role == Qt::EditRole) {
        success = m_data.UpdateRow(index, value);
    }

    if(success) {
        emit dataChanged(index, index);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now you see that the UpdateRow() function gets called here on an edit. That function should find the unique id in the map and update the appropriate members of its CBDataRow struct. My problem is that I have no idea how to get the unique ID out of the QModelIndex object that gets passed into the edit function.

For example:
User edits the "CB Name" cell of row 3. The data in row three has a unique ID of 100. That value of 100 is in the QTableView in a hidden column, column index 0. So what I need to do is simply: 
(Psuedo code)

```
it = m_data.find(unique_id);
it->second.cb_name = value.toString();
```

Since the user was editing column 1, how do i find the unique ID that is contained in column 0?

Comment: Because you have hidden your data id in a fake column I presume that you need a row indexing. If I'm right why don't use simply a vector  where each element of contains row's data? That is, why when you handle row 3 data you don't search a m_data[3] element? Is there something that I did not understand?

Comment: If i do that, I won't be able to sort the table because row three will no longer correspond to the data with an id of three.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to reimplement index() method of your model and there create indexes by using the call createIndex(row,col, unique_id);

Then in any place where you got QModelIndex, you can always extract unique_id = model_index.internalId();

Comment: The row, column arguments passed into index() will those be coming from the tableView? If so, I must not understand because that seems to get my right back where I was.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you can store your data in an array and index your element simply accessing  through  index.row():

```
QVector<CBDataRow> m_data;

....

bool CBDatabaseModel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role) {
    bool success = false;
    if(role == Qt::EditRole && index.row() < m_data.size()) {
        success = m_data.at(index.row()).UpdateRow(index.column(), value);
    }

    if(success) {
        emit dataChanged(index, index);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

if you are worrying about element sorting you can derive your model from a QSortFilterProxyModel (instead of a QAbstractTableModel) and then reimplement

```
bool CBDatabaseModel::lessThan(const QModelIndex &left,
                                   const QModelIndex &right) const
```

without define a internal id by yourself. 
I hope this can help you.